# How is Mass Defect dimensionally correct?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, mass-spectrometry

Where the Mass Defect is $∆M = M-A$. So how does $(M-A)$ have the unit of mass, as A is the mass number?

Comment: Why don't you think you can use mass units for A? Do you mean *mass excess*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cute thing about [atomic mass units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)) is that, neglecting the proton-neutron mass difference and the binding energy, the mass number *is* the mass in amu. There aren't any isotopes with a mass excess or mass deficit greater than about $100\,\mathrm{MeV}/c^2 \approx 0.1\,\mathrm{u}$.  If I tell you that this atom is tin-100 and you say "I bet the mass is 100 u," you are correct to four or five significant figures: the actual correction $\Delta M$ for tin-100 is about 60 MeV.

Answer (score 1):

According to Emilio Segre in his book *Nuclei and Particles* (pg. 190)

> $A-M$ where $M$ is the exact mass of the atom, is usually called the "mass defect," the quantity $M-A=\Delta M$ is usually called the "mass excess"...

Both $M$ and $A$ are expressed in atomic mass units, u, where the neutral carbon-12 isotope has a mass of exactly 12.0000 u, so $\Delta M = 0.$